# Split date range based on availability : Manage conflicts

Tags: java, date

I need to create a scheduler for tasks. While creating any schedule, you can give the start date and end date of the schedule. You can also add an employee to the schedule. 
However, if for an employee, the newly created schedule conflicts with the already existing schedule, the system should split the date range into available dates and schedule the task.

For eg:

> Schedule 1: Jan-10 to Jan 20 : Added employee E1 to Schedule 1. Now
>   schedule 2 is created which runs from Jan 1- Jan 25 and adding the
>   same employee,E1 to this schedule. While saving, the system should
>   split the date as Jan 1-Jan 9 and Jan 21-Jan 25.  Similar way, if
>   another schedule for the same employee is the date range of Jan 22-Jan
>   29, it should split the range as Jan 25 - Jan 29.

What is the best way to achieve this in Java ?

The logic I can now think of :

When a new schedule comes, iterate through all the previous schedules and compare the date ranges and split the date based on the availability(with for loops). But it looks very ugly logic if there are many conflicting schedules.

Is there any libraries available which does this kind of date range manipulations?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a *tool, library or favorite off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have tried using the normal for loops for finding the conflicts and splitting it. But I feel I am trying to reinvent the wheel and the code doesnt look neat also. In the java world, there will be many libraries available which can split the date-ranges based on the conflicts(eg: apache commons for string related manipulations).

Comment: First Schedule : Jan 10-Jan 20. 2nd Schedule : Jan 6-Jan 21 : This should be split as Jan 6-Jan8, Jan 21-Jan 21. 3rd Schedule : Jan5-Jan25 : This should be split as Jan 5-Jan5, Jan 8-Jan9, Jan21-Jan 25. As the no of schedules increases, the condition to check the available date ranges increases, right? I was just going crazy thinking about implementing all the scenarios. Also, some schedule can be created for a month only on mondays and wednesdays. All these needs to be taken care.